# Obj-C - Return annotations of a class to MapView after they've been removed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the below block of code to remove all Annotations of a class from my MapView, and it works great.

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, retain) NSMutableArray *breweryAnnotations;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
  -(void)removeBreweries {
        
self.breweryAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.breweryAnnotations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.mapView.annotations count]];
         for (int i = 0; i < [self.mapView.annotations count]; i++) {
             
        if ([[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[BreweryAnnotation class]]) {
           [self.breweryAnnotations addObject:[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
          }
         }
    
         [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.breweryAnnotations];
   
    }
```

That said, I'm now trying to write a block that returns all previously removed annotations of the class back to my map. Any idea how I can do this (seeing as how now the count of BreweryAnnotations on the map is technically 0)?

To recall the annotations:

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.breweryAnnotations];
```

Comment: I think you need to retain ```annotationsToRemove``` as you want to add them back. Say you put it in an ivar, then you can simply do ```[self.mapView addAnnotations:self.annotationsToRemove]``` when you want to add them back.

Comment: In other words `[self.mapView addAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];` adds the annotations to the map that are the annotations of the map with this. Aka nothing changed apart from CPU load :D ps: hope you all are well ^^

Comment: @OlSen Yes all is well, with a warm heart ... @Brittany I think you should name that ivar something like ```breweryAnnotations``` and then in the ```removeBreweries``` message replace all the ```annotationsToRemove``` with ```self.breweryAnnotations```. In fact, you should consider doing all of this using your VC's ```undoManager``` to make life easy.

Comment: See code edits above @skaak. Your suggestion makes complete sense. I recall the annotations and they populate the self.breweryAnnotations array when logged, but the annotations are still missing from the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Improving my improvements.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray * breweryAnnotations;  // Keep unmutable and use nonatimic not retain

@end

@implementation ViewController

- ( void ) removeBreweries
{
    // Iterate this way - very efficient
    // Retain
    self.breweryAnnotations = [self.mapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock: ^ BOOL ( id obj, NSDictionary * d ) {
        
        return [obj isKindOfClass:BreweryAnnotation.class];
        
    }]];

    // Now remove
    [self.mapView removeAnnotations:self.breweryAnnotations];
}

// Toggle with undo / redo
- ( void ) toggleBreweryAnnotations
{

    // Test for nil
    if ( self.breweryAnnotations )
    {
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:self.breweryAnnotations];
        self.breweryAnnotations = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        [self removeBreweries];
    }

    // Now you have undo / redo
    [self.undoManager registerUndoWithTarget:self
                     handler: ^ ( id target) {

        [target toggleBreweryAnnotations];

    }];
}
```

There are a few minor changes to the ivar and your code - see the comments for the reason. I trust these are improvements. I also use the undo manager to toggle the annotations as an enhancement that you may consider. Now I am not sure if this will work as I did not test it this side, but it should hopefully work.

Since this does not really *change* your code I suspect that you may not be able to reuse an annotation but I am not sure about this. But see how it goes and let me know and we take it from there.

Comment: nice improvement. Is the brewery beer==true?

Comment: @OlSen <hic> ```NSLog ( @"VGhlIER1dGNoIGJlZXIgaXMgZ3JlYXQgYnV0IEkgc3VzcGVjdCBHZXJtYW4gaXMgYmV0dGVyLg==" );```